# Wordpress can't find wp-admin/edit.php - BUT it's there?

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

I haven't come across this before, I created a new page template and uploaded it via ftp and then when I went to edit my pages I got a 404:

---

Not Found

The requested URL /***/wp-admin/edit.php was not found on this server.

### Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

All of my other edit pages are working fine, but edit pages (from dashboard) is returning the above error.

I've already deleted the new page template file, but I took a look first, and there was nothing wrong with it.

When I tried to access this page from Chrome, I got a warning saying that the page was being directed to payvin.com, I clicked "go anyways" and got the 404 again.

Pages on the front end are working fine.

Anyone come across this before?

thanks!

Comment: What code are you looking for Tamil?

Comment: what u code in new page template

Comment: But that is not even on the server anymore, and it's from a personal template that I've used at least 50 times...

Answer (score 0):

Search your code for that asterisk. That line likely has the source of the error. Beyond that, Tamil is right – You need to provide more information, including code, before anyone can effectively help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help & @Tamil - turns out there was weird issue server-side. Got my hosting company to resolve it.